# Safe Message Queue with multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Here is what I essentially have:

I have thread A that periodically checks for messages and processes them.

Threads B and C need to send messages to A.

The problem arises when B and C or B or C try to send a message to A while A is processing a message and thus accessing the queue.

How is this problem usually solved?

Thanks

Comment: are you working with win32 or posix?  It would help me clean up my little pseudocode example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normally solved using [mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex), or other multi-thread protection mechanisms.

If you are working on windows, MFC provides the [CMutex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt45160e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this problem.

If you are working on a posix system, the posix api provides the [`pthread_mutex_lock`, `pthread_mutex_unlock`, and `pthread_mutex_trylock` functions](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexLocking).

Some basic pseudocode would be handy to demonstrate their use in your case:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex; *or* CMutex mutex;
Q queue;  // <-- both mutex and queue are global state, whether they are
          //     global variables, or passed in as parameters, they must
          //     be the shared by all threads.

int threadA(/* params */){
    while( threadAStillRunning ){
        // perform some non-critical actions ...
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex) *or* mutex.Lock()
        // perform critical actions ...
        msg = queue.receiveMessage()
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex) *or* mutex.Unlock()
        // perform more non-critical actions
    }
}

int threadBorC(/* params */){
    while( theadBorCStillRunning ){
        // perform some non-critical actions ...
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex) *or* mutex.Lock()
        // perform critical actions ...
        queue.sendMessage(a_msg)
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex) *or* mutex.Unlock()
    }
}
```

For all three threads, their ability to act on the queue hinges on their ability to acquire the mutex - they will simply block and wait until the mutex is acquired.  This prevents conflicts arising from the use of that resource.

Comment: Nate's answer is correct, but note that while mutexes are simple to use, they may not be suitable for very high-throughput scenarios because they have a relatively high overhead.

Comment: Ah, but so do threads in general ;^)  Seriously though, different platforms have different weaknesses when it comes to thread-protection; there are some out there whose mutexes are registered with the kernel (I'm looking at you, windows), and others where mutexes are just "wrappers" around atomic checks (which barely costs a thing).

Comment: @Nate: On Windows, you're probably looking for Critical Sections, which are also very cheap.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes, Critical Sections have that advantage (and I do very much like them), but "idiomatically" they're not supposed to used for data protection, but just be used inside functions that are not reentrant that get called from multiple threads.  I suppose that's why I didn't mention them.  If you don't mind breaking out of that idiom, though, they are an inexpensive solution.

Comment: @Nate: I've never heard that philosophical argument concerning critical sections.  They are often used for data synchronization.

Comment: @Nate, I gather that even critical sections (and equivalent) can have a significant impact on performance when contention for the resource is high.  I'm thinking of the sort of thing discussed here http://www.futurechips.org/tips-for-power-coders/parallel-programming-tutorial-parallelizing-somewhat-complex-code-part-1.html

Comment: I've heard that there are alternative algorithms where you don't lock the entire queue structure simultaneously but only parts of it at a time, but I know nothing about them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - not only is the contention for the resource high, but the amount of computation is relatively small.  This means the percentage of time performing context switches comes to actually weigh down the execution of the algorithm itself.  As I said higher up, threads have overhead in general.  Mutexes (in windows, as we were discussing) are even more expensive, and the way around it is by using critical sections; in a test we ran at work on an enormously parallel program (~100 threads), we saw a speedup of double (or so, I forget the exact number).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on windows or if you are implementing something which is cross platform in C++, try using the Queue from ACE libraries.

```
ACE_Message_Queue<ACE_MT_SYNCH> *msg_queue;
```

As a sample from ACE library samples, You can then use 
For putting message to the queue:

```
  ACE_NEW_RETURN (mb,
              ACE_Message_Block (rb.size (),
              ACE_Message_Block::MB_DATA,
              0,
              buffer),
              0);
  mb->msg_priority (ACE_Utils::truncate_cast<unsigned long> (rb.size ()));
  mb->wr_ptr (rb.size ());

  ACE_DEBUG ((LM_DEBUG,
          "enqueueing message of size %d\n",
          mb->msg_priority ()));

 // Enqueue in priority order.
 if (msg_queue->enqueue_prio (mb) == -1)
ACE_ERROR ((LM_ERROR, "(%t) %p\n", "put_next"));
```

for getting from queue:

```
 ACE_Message_Block *mb = 0;

 msg_queue->dequeue_head (mb) == -1;
 int length = ACE_Utils::truncate_cast<int> (mb->length ());

 if (length > 0)
   ACE_OS::puts (mb->rd_ptr ());

  // Free up the buffer memory and the Message_Block.
  ACE_Allocator::instance ()->free (mb->rd_ptr ());
  mb->release ();
```

The advantage is you can change the synchronization primitive very easily without having to write too much of code.